# Creating a word from a random set of specific letters

Tags: ruby, random, generator, letters

I'm trying to generate a word with a specific set of letters.

The first letter of the word must contain the letters P,G,T,K the second A,E,I,O,U

I have tried generating them with the code blow with no success.  Once I store all of these random letters as variables I will then join them together to make the randomized word

```
letter1 = rand(80,84,75,71).chr
letter2 = rand(97,101,105,111,117,121).chr

name = letter1 + letter2 + letter2 + letter1 + letter2

puts name
```

Comment: how is that name obtained? always 5 chars? always 1 2 2 1 2?

Comment: I hope you mean "code below", not "code blow"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
puts 'PGTK'[rand(4), 1] + 'AEIOU'[rand(5), 1]
```

For some real fun, use actual noise-derived entropy:

```
def noise_index s
  s[@f.sysread(1).unpack('C').first/256.0*s.length, 1]
end
def run
  open '/dev/random', 'r' do |f|
    @f = f
    100.times do
      puts noise_index('PGTK') + noise_index('AEIOU')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: actually you have to repeat that a bit but that's the essence of it

Comment: Note that under Ruby 1.9+ you don't need the `,1` i.e. `'PGTK'[rand 4]`

Comment: @Phrogz, sure, and also, `unpack('C').first` can be `ord`. (I try to post widely-compatible examples.)

Answer (score 2):

If you need just a final word of two letters:

```
['PGTK', 'AEIOU'].map { |s| s.chars.to_a.sample }.join
```

Or following the example in your question:

```
letter1, letter2 = ['PGTK', 'AEIOU'].map { |s| s.chars.to_a.sample }
name = letter1 + letter2 + letter2 + letter1 + letter2
```

Comment: Thank you for the great feedback!  Both were excellent suggestions.  The was the first use I have seen of .map.  Just learning ruby and love seeing all of these different ways of achieving the end goal :)